# Multiple File Options When Upload File in Input Accept Attribute

Tags: html

I want to show multiple file type option when upload the files.

I refer to this: http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/LzLcZ/144/ .

It works great when only one type of file is appear on the option.

```
<p>Only show Excel (.xlsx) files...</p>
<input type="file" accept="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" ID="fileSelect" runat="server" />
```

but it will show 'Custom Files' when it has multiple options. as shown in image below.

```
<p>Show .xls, .xlsx, .csv files...</p>
<input type="file" accept=".csv, .pdf" ID="fileSelect" runat="server" />
```

[image]

Is there any way to show multiple options (1row for PDF, 1row for image, 1row for Excel, etc) in the file type dropdown menu? Instead of showing 'Custom Files'?

Comment: which one is your code 1st one or second one/..? and i think you  need to change your accept attribute's criteria it's working as you wrote code in html so what you need .?? or what is the problem.?

Comment: oky got the point you want to make all as upload as one but want to make choosy in file format

Answer (score 47):

hi i have tried this and worked

> the problem was the space you have given between the **.csv, .pdf**
>   as i thought

```html
<p>MY CUSTOM ONE</p>
<input type="file" accept="image/*,video/*,.pdf,.csv" ID="fileSelect" runat="server" />
```

here is your updated fiddle work

[DEMO code working](http://jsfiddle.net/LzLcZ/1159/)

Comment: @hahahaha check out the answer

Comment: It works on Firefox, but not on Chrome... Chrome still shows "Custom Files".

Answer (score 1):

For PDFs in 2023 via chrome

```
image/*, application/pdf
```